# Suddenly docker run can't find libz.so.1

Tags: command-line, java, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker, libraries

I was using docker build and docker run just fine for weeks.  The executable I want to put in a container runs fine also.
Suddenly I get this error I don't understand:

root@DESKTOP-EVLULFV:/home/simple/simple# docker run -i -p 8080:8080 --name simple --platform linux/amd64 quarkus/simple

./application: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

libz.so.1 is in
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu   and I put that folder in my path.

I build my docker image succesfully with:

docker build -f Dockerfile.native -t quarkus/simple .

I would like to inspect the container, but it does not run.

How can I tell Docker where libz.so.1 is?

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind, fixed it

I removed the following junk from my docker file.

```
FROM busybox

COPY . /build-context

WORKDIR /build-context

CMD find .
```

This is what worked:

```
####
# This Dockerfile is used in order to build a container that runs the Quarkus application in native (no JVM) mode.
#
# Before building the container image run:
#
# ./mvnw package -Dnative
#
# Then, build the image with:
#
# docker build -f Dockerfile.native -t quarkus/simple .
#
# Then run the container using:
#
# docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 quarkus/simple
#
###
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```